# trying to understand 'if ... else' loop in perl

Tags: perl

New to programming and am testing some perl scripts.
Two sets of data and the task is to separate them into two different bins based on their similarity or lack thereof.

```
set 1 
chr1 122 
chr1 123 
chr2 223 
chr2 224

set2 
chr1 122 abc 
chr1 125 def 
chr2 223 ghi 
chr2 225 jkl
```

The script I wrote was as follows. My question is while `@same` shows the expected output (rows that contain the same info between set 1 and set2),  `@diff` shows something completely incomprehensible. Did I misunderstand the use of `if ... else` ? Any insight will be greatly appreciated !

```
#! usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
open FH1, "comp1.txt" or die $!;
open FH2, "comp2.txt" or die $!;
my ($v1_col1, $v1_col2);
my ($v2_col1, $v2_col2, $v2_col3);
my (@diff, @same);

while (<FH1>) {
    ($v1_col1, $v1_col2) = split /\t/, $_;
    seek FH2, 0, 0;  
    while (<FH2>) {
        ($v2_col1, $v2_col2, $v2_col3) = split /\t/, $_;
        if ($v1_col2 == $v2_col2) {
            push @same, $_;
        } else {
            push @diff, $_;
        }
    }
}
print @same, "\n";
```

Comment: You're comparing each line in `comp2.txt` with each line in `comp1.txt`. Line 2 of comp2.txt is different from line 1 of comp1.txt, and so is line 3, line 4, etc.

Comment: If you meant to compare line 1 of each file, then line 2 of each file, and so on, you shouldn't use nested loops. You should have a single loop that reads one line from each file and compares them.

Comment: `if` statements aren't loops (they don't cause code to be executed repeatedly); they are flow control statements (it decides what code gets executed next).

Answer (score 0):

This is happening:

- Read first line of set1

  - Read first line of set 2
    compare `chr1 122` with `chr1 122 abc`. Considered equal -> `chr1 122 abc` goes
    to `@same`
  - Read 2nd line of set 2
    compare `chr1 122` with `chr1 125 def`. Considered inequal -> `chr1 125 def`
    goes to `@diff`
  - Read 3rd line of set 3
    compare `chr1 122` with `chr2 223 ghi`. Considered inequal -> `chr2 223 ghi`
    goes to `@diff`

and so on. The problem now is that `chr2 223 ghi` is inequal with `chr1 122` but you expected it to be equal to `chr2 223` in set 1.

So, you have to fill `@same` first. Then fill `@diff` with the values not found in `@same`.